# Java text file remove doubles from four column text file

Tags: java, io, text-files

I have to write a code to take a text file, which contains integers and doubles, and to print the doubles in a file and the integers in another one. The text file is formatted in the following way:

```
double int int int  
double int int int  
...  
double int int int
```

It is saved in the `"raw.txt"` file.

The output should look like:

```
int int int  
int int int   
...  
int int int
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DATA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("sorted.txt"));
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("raw.txt"));
        int temp = 0, count = 1;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            try {
                temp = reader.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                reader.nextLine();
                temp = (int) reader.nextDouble();
            }
            writer.print(temp);
            if (count % 4 == 0) 
                writer.println(); 
            count++;    

        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

The current code throws an `InputMismatchException`. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: and what is wrong with this code? Is it creating a file?

Comment: The current code throws an `InputMismatchException`. I don't know why, as I did surround the only line that could throw it in a try catch block.

Comment: Most probably the exception is thrown here `reader.nextDouble();`. But without knowing your real input this is still a guess.

Comment: agree with @SubOptimal, there will be some strange string or there can be strange localed decimal point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputMismatchException` can be thrown because it is nether Integer either Double
It is much better to read a part as a String and then decide
When it is deciding, it throws `NumberFormatException` which can be catched
In following code there are two writers separated as you wanted, It could looks better than this code maybe
I have corrected your writing to file. I havent tested it but I really think if you do `writer.print(temp);`, it will put all integers without spaces, which is useless then.
Try this code, but not tested

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DATA {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter writerInt = new PrintWriter(new File("sortedInt.txt"));
        PrintWriter writerDou = new PrintWriter(new File("sortedDou.txt"));
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("raw.txt"));
        int temp = 0, countInt = 1, countDou = 1;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String next = reader.next();
            try{
                temp=Integer.parseInt(next);
                writerInt.print(temp+" ");
                if (countInt % 4 == 0) 
                    writerInt.println(); 
                countInt++;    
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                try{
                    writerDou.print(Double.parseDouble(next)+" ");
                    if (countDou % 4 == 0) 
                        writerDou.println(); 
                    countDou++;   
                }catch(NumberFormatException f){
                    System.out.println("Not a number");
                }
            }

        }
        writerInt.close();
        writerDou.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your provided code you only want to split the files and do not care about the `double` and `int` values itself. So you could handle the file as a normal text file and split the values by the separating blank character.

The snippet does some assumptions on the format of the `raw.txt` file and is not optimised. So it should be an easy task to amend it based on your needs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> rawLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("raw.txt"));
    try (Writer intWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(
            Paths.get("int_values.txt"),
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
         Writer doubleWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(
            Paths.get("double_values.txt"),
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
        for (String line : rawLines) {
            // the split might need to be amended if the values
            // are not separated by a single blank
            String[] values = line.split(" ");

            // to be amended if there are not alway four values in a row
            if (values.length != 4) {
                continue;
            }

            doubleWriter.write(values[0]);
            doubleWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());

            intWriter.write(values[1]);
            intWriter.write(' ');
            intWriter.write(values[2]);
            intWriter.write(' ');
            intWriter.write(values[3]);
            intWriter.write(' ');
            intWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```